# Unable To Install Jint 2.1.0.0

Tags: nuget, jint

I am trying to use Jint in my C# WinForms Application but NuGet is refusing to install the package. I can install other packages perfectly fine including this one called JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jint. I googled around and couldn't find anyone else with the same problem. The error says it has a problem with the .NET Framework version but it is my understanding that 4.0 should be just fine (even so, I played around with it but nothing worked).

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint/2.1.0

[image: picture of problem]

Comment: There are a number of Nuget packages called Jint, can you link to the specific one?

Comment: @BumblebeeMan This is the one I am trying to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint/2.1.0

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you on?

Comment: @BumblebeeMan VS Ultimate 2012

Comment: I have tested this on a Winform app on VS 2013, targeting .net 4.0 with no issues, have you tried the old turning your pc off and on again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package does work fine in .NET 4.0 packages. Make sure you have the latest update of the Package Manager console. If it is updated or udpating doesn't work, try restarting Visual Studio and try again.